# Cannot Install TensorFlow on this Platform

Tags: tensorflow, python-wheel

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on a computer with a J1800 CPU. I know this CPU does not have the AVX extension. I'm trying to find a wheel package of tensorflow without an AVX extension. Every wheel I try gets the same error. Here's one example:

pip3 install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/master/1.14.0/py37/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

: ERROR: tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I'm running  Python  3.8 64Bit

Does anyone know a wheel that will work on this CPU? Or am I making another mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Only tensorflow >= 2.2 is available on **python 3.8**.

In order to work with tensorflow 1.14 you need to use another version of python (3.6 or 3.7)

Comment: Actually TensorFlow 2.2 is the first version to officially support python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are installing tensorflow 1.14 on python 3.8. python 3.8 works with  TF 2.0 only. You can either change the python version.
If you have any version like 3.x you can current python version to those by alias

eg :

```
alias python3 = python3.x
```

where x > 8

other wise checkout 2.0 and reinstall for the source.